# How can i know how many users is signed in with google in android app or website?

Tags: android, google-signin

If i have added sign in with google in android ?

What is the method  to know How many users is signed in with google in android app or website also ?

I want to know successful sign in with google . If user is denied and cancel to give permission I thinks google analytics will show one click if users is canceled to give permission and did not approve permission to sign with google?

can i see through https://console.developers.google.com/?

what is the meaning of dashboard -> Traffic ,Error in https://console.developers.google.com/?

What data it shows ?

Comment: Add Analytics to Your Android App
[link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/)

Comment: I want to know successful sign in with google . If user is denied and cancel to give permission I thinks google analytics will show one click if users is canceled to give permission and did not approve permission to sign with google?

Comment: create login_type in your Login web services to get count google user

Comment: Are you saying we can get successful login data from backend

Comment: yes
just take record is user in app with google,fb,twitter or custom on success

Answer (score 0):

Add Google Analytics to your android app and track expected events. Please follow
   https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

In your case, track event or post your data to web server at this point:

```
   @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Result returned from launching the Intent from
    //   GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        //Google44
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
     //Post or track here
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I want to know successful sign in with google . If user is denied and cancel to give permission I thinks google analytics will show one click if users is canceled to give permission and did not approve permission to sign with google?

Comment: You can track event of successful login. Either integrate Google Analytics to capture such event or integrate your own web service to maintain such count.

Comment: Are you saying we can get successful login data from backend

Comment: When successful login happens, post your data to your own web server through web service. So that you will have count at your server DB. If not possible then Google Analytics is there. See in my answer, I have given the code where you have to add such procedure.

Answer (score 0):

For Android App u can use following util class that shows all login user in Android device.

public class GooglePlusUtil implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

```
public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;
public static final int G_LOGIN_CANCELLED = 12051;

private int userIdCounter = 0;
private Context mContext;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FragmentActivity mFragmentActivity;
private GoogleResponse mResponseListener;

/**
 * Instantiates a new Google util.
 *
 * @param context
 * @param activity        the context
 * @param signInPresenter
 */
public GooglePlusUtil(Context context, FragmentActivity activity, SignInPresenter signInPresenter) {
    mContext = context;
    mFragmentActivity = activity;
    mResponseListener = signInPresenter;
    initGPlus();
}

private void initGPlus() {
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleApiClient with access to the Google Sign-In API and the
    // options specified by gso.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .enableAutoManage(mFragmentActivity, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}

/**
 * Call G+ login activity.
 */
public void login() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    mFragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Crashlytics.log(connectionResult.toString());
    Log.d("ConnectionResult", "G+ " + connectionResult.toString());
}

/**
 * Parse G+ response.
 *
 * @param accountsByType account number id
 * @param acct           G+ response.
 */
public void findAuth(Account[] accountsByType, GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    matchAccountNumber(accountsByType, acct);
    new GoogleAsyncTask(accountsByType, acct).execute();
}

/**
 * userIdCounter Account Number
 *
 * @param accounts account number id
 * @param acct     G+ response.
 */
private void matchAccountNumber(Account[] accounts, GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    for (int index = 0; index < accounts.length; index++) {
        if (accounts[index].name.equals(acct.getEmail())) {
            userIdCounter = index;
            break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Google login response.
 *
 * @param result G+ instance.
 */
public void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        if (acct == null || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        findAuth(AccountManager.get(mContext).getAccountsByType("com.google"), acct);

    } else if (result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == G_LOGIN_CANCELLED) {
        ToastUtils.getInstance(mContext).showToast(mContext.getString(R.string.google_login_cancelled));
    } else {
        ToastUtils.getInstance(mContext).showToast(mContext.getString(R.string.message_not_able_to_login_via_google));
    }
}

public class GoogleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private Account[] mAccountsByType;
    private GoogleSignInAccount mGoogleSignInAccount;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Google async task.
     *
     * @param accountsByType
     * @param acct
     */
    public GoogleAsyncTask(Account[] accountsByType, GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        mAccountsByType = accountsByType;
        mGoogleSignInAccount = acct;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mContext, mAccountsByType[userIdCounter], Constants.OAUTH_URL);
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            Crashlytics.logException(e.getCause());
            AppLogger.e(e);
            mResponseListener.onTokenNotFound(e.getIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (GoogleAuthException | IOException e) {
            Crashlytics.logException(e.getCause());
            AppLogger.e(e);
        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String token) {
        IsAuthValidRequest isAuthValidRequest = new IsAuthValidRequest();
        isAuthValidRequest.setEmail(mGoogleSignInAccount.getEmail());
        isAuthValidRequest.setFirstName(mGoogleSignInAccount.getDisplayName());
        isAuthValidRequest.setLastName(mGoogleSignInAccount.getFamilyName());
        mResponseListener.onGoogleUserInfoAvailable(isAuthValidRequest, token);
    }
}

public interface GoogleResponse {

    /**
     * When user info and token found.
     *
     * @param isAuthValidRequest info instance.
     * @param token G+.
     */
    void onGoogleUserInfoAvailable(IsAuthValidRequest isAuthValidRequest, String token);

    /**
     * Invoke when auth token not found.
     *
     * @param intent      instance.
     * @param requestCode request code.
     */
    void onTokenNotFound(Intent intent, int requestCode);
}
```

}